# Windows 7 routing traffic through the gateway for local addresses

Tags: windows-7, dhcp, iscsi, route

Windows is adding a route for a local address (10.0.0.90 - my fileserver) with a gateway of (10.0.0.138 - this is my gateway), the gateway only has a 100Mbs link so all of my fileserver bound traffic is being reduced to 100mbs, if I unplug the gateway it jumps back upto 1000mbs.

The fileserver also functions as the DHCP (isc) server (i am booting from iSCSI with IET and iPXE).

Also the machine with the strange route is configured via dhcp.

Comment: More information is needed to get help. At least, we need to know more details about your network setup. For example, are you using a mask of `/8`, `/16`, `/32`, or something else?

Comment: The subnet mask is /24 255.255.255.0.

Comment: What does your network look like physically? A switch with everything connected to that, or is it more complex?

Comment: @ChrisMcK everything (just the fileserver and the windows 7 client - the router plugs in this switch also) is connected to a simple unmanaged cisco 1Gb switch.

Comment: @LukeJurgs Does the static route get removed when the router is turned off?

Comment: @ChrisMcK No it does not, it persists no mater what I do, unplug the router and reboot windows - still there. Very annoying, I've also rebooted the switch while trying several different combos to no avail.

Comment: @LukeJurgs can you remove the route using `route delete`?

Comment: @ChrisMcK no the route delete command returns "element not found" but I can delete all sorts of other routes. Even through route /f it persists, when every other route is deleted.

Comment: Could it be uPnP configuring the route? Try turning off the uPnP Device Host service on the Windows boxes and see what happens.

Comment: @ChrisMcK thanks for your help, you helped me (a lot) to at least eliminate most of the other options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone is interested, after hours of scouring google:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960104

If you are using iPXE - like me, put:

```
option routers 10.0.0.10;
```

where 10.0.0.10 is the iscsi target, like so:

```
if exists user-class and option user-class = "iPXE" {
  option routers 10.0.0.10;
  filename "";
  option root-path "iscsi:iscsi.example.com::::iqn.1992-01.com.example.iscsi:target";
}
```

in the hardware address specific isc-dhcp entry. Outside of this conditional statement you will still need to specify the network router/gateway so the iscsi boot machine can reach the the lan/wan/internet.

Windows creates an undelete-able unchange-able route that corresponds to the iSCSI target when booting from it in the routing table, whatever gateway option is set with the target is bound to the route.